# How to convert selected timestamp into firebase server timestamp android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I want to convert entered timestamp into Firebase server timestamp Android

For example selected timestamp is -> 1631724053. Note this timestamp is got from the selected date.

Want to convert timestamp(firebase server timestamp) is -> January 01, 2021 at 3:37:59 PM UTC+5:30

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify whether you're using Java or Kotlin, however you can create a [Firestore Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#public-timestamp-date-date) from an [Android date](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date)

When calling the Timestamp constructor you would pass in your date object,so make sure you're using valid Dates as outlined in the Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

An object of type Firestore [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) represents:

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

As also @Hydra already mentioned in her comment, you can convert a long value as:

```
1631724053
```

Which actually represents:

```
Wednesday, September 15, 2021 4:40:53 PM
```

Into a Firestore object bypass the time epoch to the constructor. However, a more appropriate way of handling this kind of situation is to use [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#serverTimestamp()), which is actually a token that gets sent to Firebase Firestore servers, where the actual Timestamp is determined and written into the database.